# Angular2 Http get

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives, angular2-services

I am trying to be pull data from API using Angular2, and bind it to view. After request been done, my component only gets array object **[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]**. Can I get any help on extracting the object so that **"*ngFor"** can read each object. I want to be able to bind data to view.

```
**This is my API**
[{
    _id: "578c8c670f3cd0941efb337c",
    name: "John",
    gender: "Male",
    age: "34",
    __v: 0,
},
{
    _id: "5794a90f96391dcc2436e43f",
    name: "Valur",
    gender: "Male",
    age: "22",
    __v: 0,
},
{
    _id: "5794abad70df28541eab170b",
    name: "Paul",
    gender: "Male",
    age: "43",
    __v: 0,
}]
```

UserService is like:

```
import { Http } from 'angular2/http';
constructor(private _http: Http) { }

getuser(): Observable<any> {
     return this._http.get('http://localhost:1000/api/users')
     .map(res => res.json());
}
```

This my angular with service that handle request.

```
import { UserService } from '../services/userservice';

constructor(private userService: UserService) { }
_data: Object;

getUser():void {
    this.userService.getuser()
      .subscribe(data => this._data = data,
      error => console.log(error));

    console.log(this._data); //this part doesn't pull data at all.
}


//My view
<div *ngFor="#u of _data">
   {{u.name}} //this part gives me an error
</div>

 //But when i try to pull data from "subscribe" like this:
<div>
   {{_data | json }} //data is available
</div>
```

Comment: What does the output of `{{_data | json}}` look like?

Comment: It seems you're using quite an old Angular2 version. In recent Angular2 versions the syntax is `<div *ngFor="let u of _data">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
import { UserService } from '../services/userservice';

_data: any[];
constructor(private userService: UserService) { this._data = [];}

getUser():void {
  this.userService.getuser()
    .subscribe(data => {this._data = data; console.log(this._data);}
                error => console.log(error));
 }


 //My view
 <div *ngFor="#u of _data">
   {{u?.name}} //this part gives me an error
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Günter, the error is exactly in the syntax of the *ngFor, i have tested your code, and i made a working example:

https://github.com/TheSwash/ng2-http-service

But quickly the correct syntax should be:

```
<div *ngFor="let user of users">
   {{user.name}}
</div>
```

Besides i highly recommend you to update your angular version, you're using the beta. Currently you can use Angular-CLI: https://cli.angular.io/

The example above is made with Angular-CLI.